# How to install Windows ODBC on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

I want to install and run Open System Architech, a db schema design tool.
Before I can do that, I need to install Windows ODBC.  The latest instructions I can find are [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/02/08/odbc-driver-13-1-for-linux-released/)  They go up to version 16.04.  I am running 17.04.

I manually copied the file:

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/17.10/prod.list
```

to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

note that microsoft do have a repository for 17.04 at:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/17.04/prod zesty main
```

and I do have a 64 arch PC.

I then ran:

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msobcsql=13.2.4.0-1
```

It returned the error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package msobcsql
```

The command

```
apt-cache search msobcsql
```

returned null.

When I run:  `sudo apt-get update`

the response includes:

```
Hit:17 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/17.04/prod zesty InRelease
```

What else can I try???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're searching for the packet `msobcsql`, while the correct name is `msodbcsql` (you're missing the 'd' ;) ). Also, the repository you're using doesn't offer the package in version 13.2.4.0-1. It only supplies versions 13.1.9.0-1 and 13.1.9.1-1.

Comment: Hi  That fixed the problem.  How did you see what versions the repository offers??

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark.

Comment: @user643684 A repository is, in simple terms, a defined directory structure on a server, plus some files with meta data. So I just went to to the URL you provided (https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/17.04/prod/) and looked from there: pool (contains all packages) -> main (the section) -> m (the first letter) -> msodbcsql (the package). There you can see the two deb files that are available.